# I have a list of strings, some strings have two strings in one space, where there is a space I need to break that into two separate strings

Tags: pandas, string, list, split

`['KIWI', 'KIWI', '0', 'B19 KDAW'`]

here a portion of the list, as you can see the last one is 'B19 KDAW' but I need to break that into:

```
['KIWI', 'KIWI', '0', 'B19', 'KDAW']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tag `pandas` let us do `split` with `explode` then `tolist`

```
n_l = pd.Series(l).str.split().explode().tolist()
Out[143]: ['KIWI', 'KIWI', '0', 'B19', 'KDAW']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way:

```
import pandas as pd

l = ['KIWI', 'KIWI', '0', 'B19 KDAW ']
a = pd.Series(l).str.split(' ', n=1, expand=True).stack().tolist()
a
```

Output:

```
['KIWI', 'KIWI', '0', 'B19', 'KDAW ']
```